# Negative confidence interval for geom_smooth() in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

I have an experiment where participants complete a questionnaire (each participant has a sumpdi score for this) and an experiment with two types of (within-participant) condition (0 and 25).

I want to plot mean task response across sumpdi scores and conditions, but I am having trouble depicting confidence intervals.

I first aggregate the data:

```
 agg_forplot<- aggregate(Response ~ sumpdi+ Condition, df_forplot,
 FUN=mean)
```

I then create a plot in ggplot2:

```
Plot_C<-ggplot(agg_forplot, aes(x=sumpdi, y=Response, colour=Condition))+ geom_smooth(method='lm', se=T, fill='light blue')+geom_point()+
     ylab("Mean % 'Tone Present' Responses")+ xlab('Summary PDI Score') + labs(color= 'Condition') +
      scale_color_manual(labels = c("No tone", "25%"), values= c("#5CC0C0","#FF88FF"))+  mytheme

Plot_C
```

[image: Initial Plot]

The 'se' setting in geom_smooth() generates a negative value for the confidence interval around summary PDI score=0. However, it is obviously not possible to get a negative percentage.

Why does this happen and how can I correct this? I have tried adding the argument `+ylim(0,1)` but this removes the confidence interval completely from this section of the graph.

*Edit*
Here is the output of dput(agg_forplot) to show my data:

```
structure(list(sumpdi = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 0, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11), Condition = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("0", "25", "50", "75"), class = "factor"), 
    Response = c(0.0636323497219099, 0.0851942941465814, 0.0885739075300753, 
    0.0917113758765922, 0.0329839417565963, 0.0784596540124087, 
    0.102004605958778, 0.0945945945945946, 0.0762726196516151, 
    0.0422535211267606, 0.263157894736842, 0.276791358215455, 
    0.343362166227905, 0.314720315633304, 0.264764719482896, 
    0.23228019576997, 0.291160062315599, 0.238023716545795, 0.540540540540541, 
    0.36038961038961, 0.117647058823529, 0.533333333333333)), row.names = c(NA, 
-22L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have also since noticed that generating means by aggregating across Pt_ID prevents negative confidence interval values (see plot below), but I am unsure why this is:

```
agg_forplot<- aggregate(Response ~ sumpdi+ Condition+ Pt_ID, df_forplot, FUN=mean)
```

[image: Edited plot with Pt_ID-aggregated data]

The output for dput(agg_forplot):

```
structure(list(sumpdi = c(5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 4, 3, 3, 6, 6, 0, 0, 
6, 6, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 
0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 3, 3, 8, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 7, 7, 3, 3, 0, 0, 
6, 6, 0, 0, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 
5, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 8, 8, 2, 2, 11, 11, 4, 4, 5, 5, 9, 9, 5, 
5, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), Condition = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("0", "25", "50", "75"), class = "factor"), 
    Pt_ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
    6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 
    12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 
    18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 
    24L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 
    30L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 
    36L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 
    42L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 
    48L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 51L, 52L, 52L), levels = c("1006", 
    "1007", "1013", "1014", "1017", "1020", "1021", "1022", "1024", 
    "1026", "1028", "1032", "1033", "1034", "1036", "1037", "1039", 
    "1040", "1041", "1042", "1043", "1045", "1046", "1047", "1051", 
    "1053", "1055", "1056", "1057", "1058", "1059", "1060", "1061", 
    "1063", "1064", "1065", "1066", "1069", "1071", "1072", "1073", 
    "1074", "1078", "1079", "1085", "1086", "1087", "1088", "1089", 
    "1090", "1092", "1093"), class = "factor"), Response = c(0.0882352941176471, 
    0.108108108108108, 0.230769230769231, 0.25, 0.117647058823529, 
    0.303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0.24390243902439, 
    0.175675675675676, 0.472222222222222, 0.115942028985507, 
    0.166666666666667, 0.0289855072463768, 0.024390243902439, 
    0.0526315789473684, 0.0882352941176471, 0.0133333333333333, 
    0.307692307692308, 0.0571428571428571, 0.189189189189189, 
    0, 0.0571428571428571, 0.114285714285714, 0.27027027027027, 
    0.0571428571428571, 0.354838709677419, 0.0294117647058824, 
    0.129032258064516, 0.0571428571428571, 0.515151515151515, 
    0.0579710144927536, 0.0294117647058823, 0.027027027027027, 
    0.846153846153846, 0.0714285714285714, 0.263157894736842, 
    0.145161290322581, 0.131578947368421, 0.150684931506849, 
    0.255813953488372, 0.174603174603175, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.222222222222222, 0.34375, 0.0422535211267606, 0.0769230769230769, 
    0.0135135135135135, 0.114285714285714, 0.0945945945945946, 
    0.540540540540541, 0.0657894736842105, 0.315789473684211, 
    0.0273972602739726, 0.266666666666667, 0.0675675675675676, 
    0.233333333333333, 0.0410958904109589, 0.142857142857143, 
    0.0138888888888889, 0.166666666666667, 0.0833333333333333, 
    0.2, 0.228571428571429, 0.205882352941176, 0.0441176470588235, 
    0.0857142857142857, 0.028169014084507, 0.375, 0.0163934426229508, 
    0.193548387096774, 0.391304347826087, 0.5, 0, 0.194444444444444, 
    0.0625, 0.333333333333333, 0.0307692307692308, 0.457142857142857, 
    0.128571428571429, 0.205128205128205, 0.0933333333333333, 
    0.473684210526316, 0, 0.378378378378378, 0.0769230769230769, 
    0.542857142857143, 0.263157894736842, 0.533333333333333, 
    0, 0.36, 0.05, 0.3125, 0.0422535211267606, 0.117647058823529, 
    0, 0.257142857142857, 0.0151515151515152, 0.235294117647059, 
    0.157894736842105, 0.696969696969697, 0.0277777777777778, 
    0.424242424242424, 0.2, 0.378378378378378)), row.names = c(NA, 
-104L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If you just want to zoom in then instead of `ylim(0,1)` (which removes any data that falls outside the limits) you can use `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1))`. See the `ggplot2` [docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_cartesian.html) for more. For discussion of the general issue, see [What should I do when a confidence interval includes an impossible range of values?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55598/what-should-i-do-when-a-confidence-interval-includes-an-impossible-range-of-valu) on Cross Validated.

Comment: Thank you,  but this still does not change the negative values of the confidence interval showing on the graph?

Comment: It would be easy to show you how to do this, but we would need a [mre], including sample data to do it properly. Perhaps you could [edit] your question to include the output of `dput(agg_forplot)`?

Comment: @AllanCameron thank you for your help; I hope the above edits make the query clearer.

Comment: Not related to the question, but please consider using a colourblind safe palette

Answer (score 2):

The essential problem you have is that you are trying to do linear regression on proportion data. This doesn't work because the errors are assumed to be gaussian and therefore the model fit will have nonsensical confidence intervals.

The best way to do this would be via logistic regression if you have the original binary data, but your data seems to come in proportion format. You *could* use beta regression, but AFAIK the `betareg` package doesn't allow confidence intervals.

One other option is to transform your response variable into a logistic scale, fit the model, get the predictions, then reverse the transform:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- agg_forplot %>%
  group_by(sumpdi, Condition) %>%
  summarize(Response = mean(Response), .groups = 'drop')

mod <- lm(Response ~ sumpdi*Condition, within(df, Response <- qlogis(Response)))
pred_df <- data.frame(sumpdi = rep(seq(0, 11, length = 200), 2),
                      Condition = rep(c('0', '25'), each = 200))

preds <- predict(mod, pred_df, se.fit = TRUE)

pred_df$Response <- plogis(preds$fit)
pred_df$upper <- plogis(preds$fit + 1.96 * preds$se.fit)
pred_df$lower <- plogis(preds$fit - 1.96 * preds$se.fit)

ggplot(df, aes(sumpdi, Response, colour = Condition, group = Condition)) + 
  geom_ribbon(data = pred_df, aes(ymax = upper, ymin = lower,
                                  fill = after_scale(alpha(colour, 0.2))),
              linetype = 0) +
  geom_line(data = pred_df) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab('Summary PDI Score') + 
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("No tone", "25%"), 
                     values= c("orangered","deepskyblue4")) + 
  scale_y_continuous("Mean % 'Tone Present' Responses", limits = c(0, 0.6)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you; I actually did run a logistic mixed model with the original data (which has 'Response' as a binary variable). I just aggregated the data to try and produce a plot as I wasn't sure how to plot the mixed model

Comment: The `ggeffects` and `sjPlot` packages are useful for plotting